# Creating a subset of unique entries for a recursive list in R

Tags: r, recursion, duplicates, unique, subset

I have the following data set `df`

```
name  draught   nav_status  date
 A      22          0       24/12/2014
 A      22          0       25/12/2014
 A      11          5       26/12/2014
 A      11          1       27/12/2014
 B      22          0       24/12/2014
 B      22          0       25/12/2014
 B      22          0       26/12/2014
 B      22          5       27/12/2014
 B      9           0       28/12/2014
 B      22          0       29/12/2014
```

from this data set, I need to extract the unique draught values for each object of the list.

I am fairly new to R and have made the following attempts

```
y <- subset(df,!duplicated(df[,draught]),)
```

and

```
Dup <- function(x){
x <- x[!duplicated[x$draught],]
y <- lapply(df, Dup)
```

But this deletes the draught entries for the entire data. I went through some literature regarding split-apply and combine techniques and also tries those options.
Please provide some guidance, literature so as to solve this problem.

The result should be

```
name  draught  nav_status  date
 A     22          0        24/12/2014
 A     11          5        26/12/2014
 A     11          1        27/12/2014
 B     22          0        25/12/2014
 B     9           0        28/12/2014
```

I even tried to `subset`the data based on first and last entries by arranging them sequentially and deleting the duplicate entries, but there was loss of data.Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table` library you can arrive at the result by:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)
unique(dt, by = c('name', 'draught'))
```

One thing though. Why you have two entries of a pair A 11 in your desired result?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! If you may have already observed, the nav_status column has a change and that is valuable sometimes too. Thanks